# The "strongest password"

Tags: combinatorics

I have an app which is protected by a four-digit-PIN and the user got five attempts at logging in before the account is locked.

Now, one of my customers wants to "strengthen" the security and advocate for another solution:

- six-digit-PIN
- NO "same digit next to each other": e.g.: **11**3945 or 39**55**94
- NO "three-running numbers": e.g.: **123**654 or 53**789**3

Now to the question: Which solution is the strongest?

I can calculate the four-digit pretty easy, but how do I calculate the other one?

Thanks!

**Update**

You get what you ask for - especially when working with math :)

So, what I was asking for was the number of combinations for both number sequences.

Reading through the answers and comments it has come clear to me that it really doesn't matter. If you have 5 guesses then it doesn't matter if you have 10.000 or ~800.000 to choose from.
More important is ruling out 1234 and day of birth. In my situation, I actually have the users day of birth so I have something to check against.

Thanks for a great discussion!

Comment: Taking a historical perspective, you should acquaint yourself with the cryptanalysis of the Enigma machine. In particular, the Enigma algorithm never encrypted a letter to itself. This was thought to make it more secure by its engineers, but it had the effect of making the machine dramatically less secure. This was one of the many steps which allowed the Allied Powers to break Enigma. I'm not an expert in crypto by any means, but the general notion is that you want your keyspace to be as large as possible.

Comment: I think this belongs on [crypto.SE], not here.

Comment: I think it's probably a question about crypto, but I think that this can be framed out as a probability question. If OP is concerned about security practices more than the mathematics, then it should be migrated. Otherwise, I think it's a great way to get neophytes to think about combinatorics.

Comment: Casper, please clarify -- are you primarily concerned about it as a security issue (e.g. there's considerations related to more than just probability), in which case it may be a better fit elsewhere -- or are you asking a primarily probability question (which fits here)?

Comment: Theoretically---if you are focused solely on brute force attacks---more possibilities means more security so restrictions such as the no-same-digit or no-runs-of-3 reduce the number of possibilities thus they are strictly weaker. However, practically (as user777 touches on) people aren't choosing random pins. If the users are lazier than they are paranoid, many of them may choose pins such as "000000" or "123456", which then makes things less secure.

Comment: But the 5-try-then-lockout rule would highly mitigate the risks of a brute-force attack, so additional steps to mitigate that attack seem mostly pointless. I agree with Gregor that the larger hazard, given the lockout policy, is lazy users.

Comment: I am voting to (temporarily) close this question as unclear, on the grounds that the OP's intentions are not yet obvious. I'd really prefer to see @Glen_b's question answered, so we know whether this should be treated as a combinatorics/probability question or as something that is better migrated.

Comment: This is **not a statistical issue**, you should asked this question rather on: http://security.stackexchange.com Most password cracking software **will not** do simple brute-force attack (try all the possible combination of numbers) but will take into consideration commonly used passwords and patterns (letters near by on keyboard, letters on extreme ends of keyboard) etc. so the only password that is secure is **long and truthfully random** or at least **long and unguessable** (e.g. "correct horse battery staple", c.f. https://xkcd.com/936/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've asked a statisticians forum for help on this question, so I'll provide a statistically-based answer. Thus it's reasonable to assume you're interested in the probability of guessing a PIN at random (for some definition of random), but that's reading more into the question than is provided.

My approach will be to enumerate all possible options without restricting, then subtract the void options. This has a sharp corner, to it, though, called the inclusion-exclusion principle, which corresponds to the intuitive idea that you don't want to subtract the same thing from a set twice!

In a six-digit PIN with no restrictions and a decimal number system, there are $10^6$ possible combinations, from $000 000$ to $999 999:$ each digit has 10 options.

Consider what "two adjacent, identical" digits looks like: $AAXXXX$, where the positions labelled $A$ are the same and $X$ can be any decimal digit. Now consider how many other ways the string $AA$ can be arranged in six digits: $XAAXXX$, $XXAAXX$, $XXXAAX$, and $XXXXAA$. So for any particular ordering (one of those options), there are at least $10^4$ combinations, since there are $10^4$ digits without restriction. Now, how many choices of $A$ are there? We're working with decimal digits, so there must be 10. So there are $10^5$ choices for a particular ordering. There are five such orderings, so there are $5\times10^5$ arrangements that satisfy this definition. (What this means in terms of security might be measured in terms of an information-theoretic measure of how much this reduces the entropy of the PIN space.)

Now consider what consecutive numbers look like. In the string $ABCXXX$, if we know A, we also know B and C*: if A is 5, then B is 6 and C is 7. So we can enumerate these options:

- 012XXX
- 123XXX
- 234XXX
- 456XXX
- 789XXX

and at this point it's unclear if there's a "wrapping around." If there is, we also include

- 890XXX
- 901XXX

Each solution has $10^3$ associated combinations, by the same reasoning as above. So just count out how many solutions there must be. Keep in mind to count alternative orderings, such as $XABCXX.$

Now we get to the sharp corner, which is the inclusion-exclusion principle. We've made the set of all six-digit PINs into three sets:

A. Permissible PINs
  B. Void PINs due to "adjacent digits"
  C. Void PINs due to "sequential digits"

But there's an additional subtlety, which is that there are some 6-digit numbers  which can be allocated to both $B$ and $C$. So if we compute $|S|=|A|-|B|-|C|,$ we're subtracting out those numbers twice, and our answer is incorrect. The correct computation is $|S|=|A|-|B|-|C|+|B\cap C|,$ where $B\cap C$ is the set of elements in both $B$ and $C$. So we must determine How many ways can a number fall in both $B$ and $C$.

There are several ways this can occur:

- $AABCXX$
- $ABCXDD$
  and so on. So you have to work out a systematic approach to this as well, as well as a way to keep track of alternative orderings. Using the same logic that I've applied above, this should be very tractable, if slightly tedious. Just keep in mind how many alternative ways there might be to satisfy both B and C.

Slightly more advanced approaches would take advantage of basic combinatoric results and the fundamental theorem of counting, but I chose this avenue as it places the smallest technical burden on the reader.

Now, for this to be a well-formed probability question, we have to have some measure of probability for each arrangement. In the assumption of a naive attack, one might assume that all digit combinations have equal probability. In this scenario, the probability of a randomly-chosen combination is $\frac{1}{|S|}$ If that's the kind of attack you're most interested in preventing, though, then the proposed set of criteria obviously weakens the system, because some combinations have are forbidden, so only a dumb attacker would try them. I leave the rest of the exercise to the reader.

The wrinkle of "five until lockout" is decidedly the better guard against unauthorized access, since in either the 4-digit or the 6-digit scheme, there are a very large number of options, and even five different, random guesses have a low probability of success. For a well-posed probability question, it's possible to compute the probability of such an attack succeeding.

But other factors than probability of sequences of numbers may influence the security of the PIN mechanism. Chiefly, people tend not to choose PINs at random! For example, some people use their date of birth, or DOB of children, or some similarly personally-related number as a PIN. If an attacker knows the DOB of the user, then it will probably be among the first things they try. So for a particular user, some combinations may be more likely than others.

*The sequences you list are strictly increasing, and it's unclear whether both increasing and decreasing when you say "three-running number."

Answer (score 1):

Obtaining a closed formula seems complex. However, it is quite easy to enumerate them. There are `568 916` possible codes for the second solution. Which is bigger than the number of solutions with a four digit PIN code. The code to enumerate them is below. Though not optimized, it only takes seconds to run.

Note. I assumed that the sequence had to be in increasing order (which can be easily modified in `three_running`)

```
N = 999999

candidates = range(N)

def same_consecutive_digits(x):
    x_string = str(x).zfill(6)
    for i in range(1,len(x_string)):
        if x_string[i] == x_string[i-1]:
            return True
    return False

def three_running(x):
    x_string = str(x).zfill(6)
    for i in range(2,len(x_string)):
        if int(x_string[i]) == int(x_string[i-1]) + 1 and int(x_string[i-1]) == int(x_string[i-2]) + 1:
            return True
    return False

def valid(x):
    return not same_consecutive_digits(x) and not three_running(x)

assert(same_consecutive_digits(88555))
assert(same_consecutive_digits(123))
assert(not same_consecutive_digits(852123))
assert(three_running(123456))
assert(not three_running(4587))
assert(valid(134679))
assert(not valid(123894))
assert(not valid(111111))
assert(not valid(151178))
assert(valid("031278"))

accepted = [i for i in range(N) if valid(i)]
print(len(accepted))
```

Comment: Implicit in the code, but not in your description, is the assumption that PINs will never begin with the digit "0".  That's not usually true of PINs or passwords.  The correct answer, allowing for such zeros, is 568,916.  Let's bear in mind, though, that the *relevant* answer would consider that attacks on the PIN in this constrained problem can be made much more efficient by exploiting the constraints, implying that this mere enumeration of the possibilities does not adequately represent the "strength" of the system, as pointed out in comments to the question.